# Rails: change the value of a an attribute in params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, decimal

I have a form with an input(`price`) that a user fills with values like: `12,50` or `110,90` (French prices).

So in the controller I do : `@quote = current_user.company.quotes.build!(params[:quote])`

The problem is that rails behaives with the decimals in the `US` way. So it saves the quote with the price `12.00` or `111.90`

So how do I tell rails to actually consider the european version of decimals?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

The solution is to add this method to the `Quote` model.

```
def price=(data) write_attribute(:price, data.to_s.gsub(',', '.')) end
```

This will replace `,` with `.`. Thanks Olivier for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are actually dealing with decimals convert to a decimal 12,50 -> 12.5 before storing it you can then easily perform any arithmetic on it.

It will be a string in the params so you can use sub to replace , with . You could do this in the model by overriding the setter `price=` method.

Convert it to 12,50 in the view when displaying it.