# Change comma to point type decimal in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, gsub

I have a model product, that model have attribute price with decimal type (`:precision => 20, :scale => 2`)
In the form I use format for price field that looks like : `3.000,00`, When submitting the form, price change to `3.00` . I want the price to be `3,000.00`, not `3.00`

Test with rails console

```
irb(main):001:0> p = Product.create(:price => "3.000,00")   ←[1m←[36m
(0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mBEGIN←[0m   ←[1m←[35mSQL (72.0ms)←[0m  INSERT INTO
"products" ("created_at", "price" "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Tue, 29 Apr 2 014 14:07:25 WIB
+07:00], ["price", #<BigDecimal:4c218f0,'0.3E1',9(18)>], ["updated_at", Tue, 29 Apr 2014 14:07:25 WIB +07:00]]   ←[1m←[36m
(11.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mCOMMIT←[0m
=> #<Product id: 8, price: #<BigDecimal:4bd5588,'0.3E1',9(18)>, created_at: "20 14-04-29 07:07:25", updated_at: "2014-04-29 07:07:25">
 
irb (main):002:0> p.price.to_s
=> "3.0"
```

I have tried with `gsub` for change comma to point on `before_save` and store to database, but price always change to `3.00` on database.

```
  before_save :comma_to_delimiter

  def comma_to_delimiter
    self.price = self.price.gsub(/[.,]/, '.' => ',', ',' => '.')
  end
```

I want like this :
when I input `3.000,00` to field price, on database `3,000.00` and on view price `3.000,00`

I can't figure out how to do that.
Thanks

Note : I'm using [jquery-maskMoney](http://plentz.github.io/jquery-maskmoney/) for field price with format :

```
$("#demo4").maskMoney();

<input type="text" id="demo4" data-thousands="." data-decimal="," data-prefix="R$ " />
```

Comment: worth reading through the rails internationalization guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html particularly the localize function

Answer (score 4):

Remove the delimiter character in your String, because when saving the data in the model, it takes '.' or ',' as a decimal delimiter. Try something like this.

```
before_save :format_number

def format_number
  self.price = self.price.gsub(/[.,]/, '.' => '', ',' => '.')
end
```

For the inverse purpose in your view you can use [NumberHelper](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_to_currency), so you can format as 'R$'

```
<%= number_to_currency(3000.00, unit: "R$ ", separator: ",", delimiter: ".", precision: 2) %> #=> "R$ 3.000,00"
```

Comment: A perfect answer, but can someone please explain how this works: self.price.gsub(/[.,]/, '' => ',', ',' => '.') ?

Comment: Well it just say, when a '.' character is found by the regexp, this should be replaced by '' , and if a ',' is matched it is replaced by '.' . Thats the interpretation that I have for it and works.

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting is the problem

You're sending a value of `3.000,00` into your db. [MYSQL's decimal type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) is designed to put the `decimal point` at the center of the data. I need to learn more about maths to give you a real definition (about floating points etc), but here's what I would heed from MYSQL:

> The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column remains DECIMAL(M,D),
>   although the range of values for the arguments has changed somewhat:
>
> M is ......
>
> D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the
>   scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

This says to me that MYSQL determines the number to store using the `.` Because you're sending `3.000,00`, it's treating it as `3.00`

---

**Fix**

Interested in the solution, I looked at [Wikipedia's article on decimal handling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark) - 24% of the world use the `,` as the [radix point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_point)

To handle this, you'd either need to [translate MYSQL to handle the `,`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669212/change-decimal-separator-in-mysql), but this is not part of its functionality. Instead, I would attempt to translate the format before save

Although you can do this manually, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8153188/localizing-a-text-field-containing-a-number-in-ruby-on-rails) provided the [delocalize gem](https://github.com/clemens/delocalize)

Comment: yeah rich, I have [readed this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8212795/1297435) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9549299/1297435) , and now I will try it. thanks

Comment: btw, I use PostgreSQL

Comment: Sorry, I meant to ask! I believe the formatting should still apply